# Cannot print String and Variable calculation at the same time in c# Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015

i am a beginner in C# , tried to make a console application which takes user inputs and calculate them. I tried commented way but it doesn't work but the rest. Please explain . Any suggestion on doing it more efficiently is appreciated . Thank you .

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter First Digit");
int input1 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Digit");
int input2 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

/* The following code doesn't work.
* Console.WriteLine("Total = " + input1 + input2);
* Console.Readline();
*/

int sum = input1 + input2;
Console.WriteLine("Total = " + sum);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_ exactly? You get any exception or error message? Unexpected result? Why you said "digit" by the way? When your inputs are `5` and `1`, you wanna result as `51` or `6`?

Comment: Probably you are stopped by a user that inputs something that cannot be converted to an integer. If this is the case the answer is the usual: Use Int32.TryParse

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is wrong?

Comment: In commented code you are adding a `string` to an `int` and then another `int` this make the result wrong.

Comment: Also change the `Console.Readline();` to `Console.ReadLine();` in commented code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `(` and `)` between `input1 + input2`, otherwise it will be add as tring.

```
    Console.WriteLine("Total = " + (input1 + input2));
    Console.ReadLine();
```

---

**For completeness, you should use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `int.Parse`**

`TryParse` will tell you if a `string` can convert to `int` or not. In case user input data is not a integer, below code will work ok, but your work will break.

```
int input1 = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter First Digit");
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your first data is not an interger");
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}

int input2 = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Digit");
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your second data is not an interger");
    Console.ReadLine();
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine("Total = " + (input1 + input2));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem. When you do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Total = " + input1 + input2);
```

The compiler reads from left to right and sees a string first, and decides to do string concatenation, so your result vi likely be: (if input 1 = 3 and input 2 is 4:) 
"Total = 34"

This is because the compiler "translates" this statement into

```
Console.WriteLine("Total = " + input1.ToString() + input2.ToString() );
```

Now, if you direct the compiler to think again, you simply do as in Maths, force the compiler to see input1+input2 as an individual expression:

```
Console.WriteLine("Total = " + (input1 + input2));
```

I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo there

```
   /* The following code doesn't work.
     * Console.WriteLine("Total = " + input1 + input2);
     * Console.Readline();
     */
```

Readline instead of `ReadLine()`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use TryParse in case user inputs something else that numbers

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter First Digit");
if(!int32.TryParse (Console.ReadLine(),out input1))
{
     Console.WriteLine ("Wrong Number!");
}
```

Same comment for the second number

Concerning  the error you get, you can use string.Format, it will make your code clearer:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format ("Total = {0}", input1 + input2);
Console.Readline();
```

The entire code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Calc();
    }

    static void Calc()
    {
        int input1, input2;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter First Digit");
        if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Number!");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter Second Digit");
        if (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong Number!");
            return;
        }


        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total = {0}" , input1 + input2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```